# Cannot get Cassandra Cluster to Connect

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am using the Cassandra NuGet to try and interface `cassandra` together with a `C#` application.

When I expose my `NoHostAvailableException` the reason behind the error is

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tried to change the `native_transport_port` in the `cassandra.yaml` file to something other then port 9042, but still no luck. Is there a piece that I am missing?

Comment: Where is the cluster? If a different computer from the application, have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: check firewall settings

Comment: I checked firewall settings on my machine where the cluster is (ubuntu 14.04) and from the chain INPUT systems on port 9042 target is ACCEPT and source is anywhere and destination is anywhere. Is this the settings i should have?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your problem solved by editing the **cassandra.yaml** file by changing the rpc_address .

For more details you can check out this link.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54517620/cassandra-unable-to-connect-to-any-servers-with-error-code-10061/54517739#54517739)

Let me know if still face any issue.