# Cassandra 'Unable to connect to any servers' with error code 10061

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra, pyspark

I have cassandra in my local private network and I'm trying to access from a different PC but while connecting to cassandra server I'm getting this error.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(["192.168.1.170"])
session = cluster.connect()
```

> ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.170':
>   ConnectionRefusedError(10061, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.1.170',
>   9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it")})

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2):

Though It is not a good practises but still I can help you with.
I have solved this issue by changing the **"cassandra.yaml"** file

1. Go to /cassandra/conf/ folder
2. Edit  this **"cassandra.yaml"**
3. Look for rpc_address change it to the 0.0.0.0
4. Save your  "cassandra.yaml" file
5. Restart your cassandra server

This will solve your error. Let me know If you are still facing any issue.